# boost::ptree find? or how to access deep arrays? C++

Tags: json, c++11, boost, boost-propertytree

I have been trying for too much time now, to access a json_reader ptree from the boost library.

I have a json file that is capsulated really often: (pseudo-json:)

```
"Foo": {
  "nameofFoo:"foofoo"
  "Bar": [{
    "BarFoo": 
      { BarFooDeep: { 
           BarFooDeepDeep: { 
            "BarFooValue1": 123 
            "BarFooValue2" : 456
          }
        }
      }
     "FooBar": [ {
        "FooBarDeep" :[ {
           FooBarDeepDeep:[ {
              FooBarValue1: "ineedthis"
              FooBarValue2: "andthis"
              } ]
           FooBarDeepDeep1:[ {
              FooBarValue1: "ineedthis"
              FooBarValue2: "andthis"
              } ]
        "FooBarDeep" :[ {
           FooBarDeepDeep2:[ {
              FooBarValue1: "ineedthis"
              FooBarValue2: "andthis"
              } ]
           FooBarDeepDeep3:[ {
              FooBarValue1: "ineedthis"
              FooBarValue2: "andthis"
              } ]
and so on .... won t complete this now...
```

Now I only need to get FooBarValue1 and FooBarValue2 of all FooBar.

I know ptree puts arrays together with empty childs ("")

I can access all the members by itereration over all the childs recursively.

But is there not a better way to access special values?

how does ptree find works? i always get compiler errors ...

```
ptree jsonPT;
read_json( JSON_PATH, jsonPT);
ptree::const_iterator myIT = jsonPT.find("FooBarValue1");
double mlat = boost::lexical_cast<int>(myIT->second.data());
```

> error: conversion from
>   ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree,
>   std::basic_string >::assoc_iterator’ to non-scalar type
>   ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree,
>   std::basic_string >::const_iterator’ requested
>        ptree::const_iterator myIT = jsonPT.find("FooBarValue1");

Can anyone give me a useful hint how to get access to this ptree?!?

Comment: can you please make the JSON sensible? It's too broken to say anything really

Comment: You can look at the path algorithm here for inspiration http://stackoverflow.com/a/29199812/85371 (the processing is identical for JSON, since it just works on ptrees)

Comment: The edit didn't make the json valid (not even close). I've done it for you, see my answer :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hinted in the linked answer I commented ([Boost.PropertyTree subpath processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198853/boost-propertytree-subpath-processing/29199812#29199812)), you could write your own "selector" query, so you could write stuff like:

```
read_json("input.txt", pt);

std::ostream_iterator<std::string> out(std::cout, ", ");

std::cout << "\nSpecific children but in arrays: ";
enumerate_path(pt, "Foo.Bar..FooBar..FooBarDeep1..FooBarDeepDeep6..FooBarValue2", out);

std::cout << "\nSingle wildcard: ";
enumerate_path(pt, "Foo.Bar..FooBar..FooBarDeep1..*..FooBarValue2", out);

std::cout << "\nTwo wildcards: ";
enumerate_path(pt, "Foo.Bar..FooBar..*..*..FooBarValue2", out);
```

The `enumerate_path` function need not be too complicated and takes any output iterator (so you can `back_inserter(some_vector)` just as well):

```
template <typename Tree, typename Out, typename T = std::string>
Out enumerate_path(Tree const& pt, typename Tree::path_type path, Out out) {
    if (path.empty())
        return out;

    if (path.single()) {
        *out++ = pt.template get<T>(path);
    } else {
        auto head = path.reduce();
        for (auto& child : pt) {
            if (head == "*" || child.first == head) {
                out = enumerate_path(child.second, path, out);
            }
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

As simple working demo prints:

```
Specific children but in arrays: andthis6, 
Single wildcard: andthis6, andthis7, andthis8, andthis9, 
Two wildcards: andthis1, andthis2, andthis3, andthis4, andthis6, andthis7, andthis8, andthis9,
```

That is with the following [input.txt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11026065/):

```
{
    "Foo": {
        "nameofFoo": "foofoo",
        "Bar": [{
            "BarFoo": {
                "BarFooDeep": {
                    "BarFooDeepDeep": {
                        "BarFooValue1": 123,
                        "BarFooValue2": 456
                    }
                }
            },
            "FooBar": [{
                "FooBarDeep0": [{
                    "FooBarDeepDeep1": [{
                        "FooBarValue1": "ineedthis1",
                        "FooBarValue2": "andthis1"
                    }],
                    "FooBarDeepDeep2": [{
                        "FooBarValue1": "ineedthis2",
                        "FooBarValue2": "andthis2"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "FooBarDeepDeep3": [{
                        "FooBarValue1": "ineedthis3",
                        "FooBarValue2": "andthis3"
                    }],
                    "FooBarDeepDeep4": [{
                        "FooBarValue1": "ineedthis4",
                        "FooBarValue2": "andthis4"
                    }]
                }],
                "FooBarDeep1": [{
                    "FooBarDeepDeep6": [{
                        "FooBarValue1": "ineedthis6",
                        "FooBarValue2": "andthis6"
                    }],
                    "FooBarDeepDeep7": [{
                        "FooBarValue1": "ineedthis7",
                        "FooBarValue2": "andthis7"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "FooBarDeepDeep8": [{
                        "FooBarValue1": "ineedthis8",
                        "FooBarValue2": "andthis8"
                    }],
                    "FooBarDeepDeep9": [{
                        "FooBarValue1": "ineedthis9",
                        "FooBarValue2": "andthis9"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a57e51a163150f6)</kbd>**

### Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75719ffb76659264)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Tree, typename Out, typename T = std::string>
Out enumerate_path(Tree const& pt, typename Tree::path_type path, Out out) {
    if (path.empty())
        return out;

    if (path.single()) {
        *out++ = pt.template get<T>(path);
    } else {
        auto head = path.reduce();
        for (auto& child : pt) {
            if (head == "*" || child.first == head) {
                out = enumerate_path(child.second, path, out);
            }
        }
    }

    return out;
}

int main() {

    std::ostream_iterator<std::string> out(std::cout, ", ");
    using namespace boost::property_tree;

    ptree pt;
    read_json("input.txt", pt);

    std::cout << "\nSpecific children but in arrays: ";
    enumerate_path(pt, "Foo.Bar..FooBar..FooBarDeep1..FooBarDeepDeep6..FooBarValue2", out);

    std::cout << "\nSingle wildcard: ";
    enumerate_path(pt, "Foo.Bar..FooBar..FooBarDeep1..*..FooBarValue2", out);

    std::cout << "\nTwo wildcards: ";
    enumerate_path(pt, "Foo.Bar..FooBar..*..*..FooBarValue2", out);
}
```

Comment: Wow! thx that looks really great and amazing! I ll try to integrate that in my program!

Comment: Thx for cleaning up the broken JSON, i also forgot to tell that for every FooBarDeep is a FooBarDeepName

Well that way i can get all Data from one Key, is there also a good option to get them for a Value in a Key?

All my FooBarDeep are FooBarDeep and i have (n) of them, only the FooBarDeepName = "alwaysdifferent"
now i need to read the FooBarDeepName and if its "NameOfFoo_I_want"
Write the stuff below in a vector or something similar.

I think i have to ask the People who send me this JSON why its made that stupid way.

Comment: @Druide Please. Just post a new question? With a 7 line demo JSON. Comments don't work this way, and you can't really invalidate existing answers by changing the question. I'll have a look if you post it as a clearer question.

Comment: Oh and please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

`find()` is for retrieving a child node by key; it doesn't search the whole ptree. It returns an `assoc_iterator` (or `const_assoc_iterator`), which you can convert to an `iterator` via the `to_iterator()` method on the parent:

```
ptree::const_assoc_iterator assoc = jsonPT.find("FooBarValue1");
ptree::const_iterator myIT = jsonPT.to_iterator(assoc);
```

To search the ptree, you'll need to iterate it recursively:

```
struct Searcher {
    struct Path { std::string const& key; Path const* prev; };
    void operator()(ptree const& node, Path const* path = nullptr) const {
        auto it = node.find("FooBarValue1");
        if (it == node.not_found()) {
            for (auto const& child : node) {  // depth-first search
                Path next{child.first, path};
                (*this)(child.second, &next);
            }
        } else {    // found "FooBarValue1"
            double mlat = boost::lexical_cast<int>(myIT->second.data());
            // ...
            std::cout << "Mlat: " << mlat << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Path (reversed): ";
            for (Path const* p = path; p != nullptr; p = p->prev)
                std::cout << p << ".";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
Searcher{}(jsonPT);
```

Alternatives for writing the recursive traversal would be a C++14 generic lambda, or in C++11 a type-erased concrete lambda using `std::function`.

Comment: Thank you! Hoped there is a option to not do it recursively. I ll do it now that way, and hope to get the correct one.
If i do a node.find("FooBarValue1"); i get all FooBarValue1 to mlat.
How do i know if its from FooBarDeepDeep1 or 2 or 3?

Comment: @Druide you can keep a record of the path taken to reach a particular node as you perform the recursive search.

Comment: @ecatumur I need it in c++11 and at the moment i don t get the auto rec converted in my function to work ...
Dunno maybe i need my weekend to be clear in my head ... at the moment i have the feeling i m not understanding anything anymore :/

Comment: @Druide changed to the classic functor approach.