# Iterating on xml file with boost

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I am new with boost and xml and I am trying to scan an xml file and save some specific values.

I read [this](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/parsing-xml-with-boost/) article and my question is: if the xml contains several `<sked>`, how do I iterate both of them?

maybe

```
BOOST_FOREACH ()
   BOOST_FOREACH () // nested loop
```

lets say the given xml file as follow (the purpose is to save **both** IDs):

```
<?xml version="1.0"? encoding="utf-8"?>
<arrayOfSked>
 <sked>
   <ID> 1 </ID>
   <version>2</version>
   <flight>
     <carrier>BA</carrier>
     <number>4001</number>
     <precision>0.1</precision>
   </flight>
   <flight cancelled="true">
     <carrier>BA</carrier>
     <number>4002</number>
     <precision>0.2</precision>
   </flight>
 </sked>

<sked>
   <ID> 2 </ID>
   <version>2</version>
   <flight>
     <carrier>BA</carrier>
     <number>4001</number>
     <precision>0.1</precision>
   </flight>
   <flight cancelled="true">
     <carrier>BA</carrier>
     <number>4002</number>
     <precision>0.2</precision>
   </flight>
 </sked>


</arrayOfSked>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/parsing-xml-with-boost/

Comment: May I suggest using an XML library to parse XML? Boost does not have an XML library. It has a property tree library though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking some inspiration from this older answer of mine ([boost::ptree find? or how to access deep arrays? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105711/boostptree-find-or-how-to-access-deep-arrays-c/30125315#30125315)), write a function to visit the tree nodes:

```
template <typename Tree, typename Out>
Out enumerate_nodes(Tree const& pt, typename Tree::path_type path, Out out) {
    if (path.empty())
        return out;

    if (path.single()) {
        auto name = path.reduce();
        for (auto& child : pt)
        {
            if (child.first == name)
                *out++ = child.second;
        }
    } else {
        auto head = path.reduce();
        for (auto& child : pt) {
            if (head == "*" || child.first == head) {
                out = enumerate_nodes(child.second, path, out);
            }
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Now you can simply read the file:

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
ptree pt;

{
    std::ifstream ifs("input.txt");
    read_xml(ifs, pt);
}
```

And collect the flights:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<ptree const> > flights;
enumerate_nodes<ptree>(pt, "arrayOfSked.sked.flight", back_inserter(flights));

for (ptree const& flight : flights) {
    std::cout << "Canceled:\t" << (flight.get("<xmlattr>.cancelled", false)?"yes":"no") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Carrier:\t" << flight.get("carrier", "?") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number:\t" << flight.get("number", 0) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Precision:\t" << flight.get("precision", 0.0) << "\n";
    std::cout << "------------------------------\n";
}
```

Which prints:

```
Canceled:   no
Carrier:    BA
Number: 4001
Precision:  0.1
------------------------------
Canceled:   yes
Carrier:    BA
Number: 4002
Precision:  0.2
------------------------------
Canceled:   no
Carrier:    BA
Number: 4001
Precision:  0.1
------------------------------
Canceled:   yes
Carrier:    BA
Number: 4002
Precision:  0.2
------------------------------
```

### Full Demo Online

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/898f62fad116f339)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Tree, typename Out>
Out enumerate_nodes(Tree const& pt, typename Tree::path_type path, Out out) {
    if (path.empty())
        return out;

    if (path.single()) {
        auto name = path.reduce();
        for (auto& child : pt)
        {
            if (child.first == name)
                *out++ = child.second;
        }
    } else {
        auto head = path.reduce();
        for (auto& child : pt) {
            if (head == "*" || child.first == head) {
                out = enumerate_nodes(child.second, path, out);
            }
        }
    }

    return out;
}

int main() {
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;

    {
        std::ifstream ifs("input.txt");
        read_xml(ifs, pt);
    }

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<ptree const> > flights;
    enumerate_nodes<ptree>(pt, "arrayOfSked.sked.flight", back_inserter(flights));

    for (ptree const& flight : flights) {
        std::cout << "Canceled:\t" << (flight.get("<xmlattr>.cancelled", false)?"yes":"no") << "\n";
        std::cout << "Carrier:\t" << flight.get("carrier", "?") << "\n";
        std::cout << "Number:\t" << flight.get("number", 0) << "\n";
        std::cout << "Precision:\t" << flight.get("precision", 0.0) << "\n";
        std::cout << "------------------------------\n";
    }
}
```